# Randomly selecting values from an existing matrix after adding a vector (in R)

Tags: r, matrix, sampling

Thank you so much for your help in advance!

I am trying to modify an existing matrix such that, when a new line is added to the matrix, it removes values from the preexisting matrix.

For example, I have the matrix:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 1     1    0    0
 0     1    0    0
 1     0    1    0
 0     0    1    1
```

I want to add another vector, I.vec, which has two values (`I.vec=c(0,1,1,0)`).
This is easy enough to do.  I just rbind it to the matrix.
Now, for every column where I.vec is equal to 1, I want to randomly select a value from the other rows and make it zero.
Ideally, this would end up with a matrix like:

```
[,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 1     0    0    0
 0     1    0    0
 1     0    0    0
 0     0    1    1
 0     1    1    0
```

But each time I run the iteration, I want it to randomly sample again.

So this is what I have tried:

```
mat1<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1),byrow=T, nrow=4)
I.vec<-c(0,1,1,0)
mat.I<-rbind(mat1,I.vec)
mat.I.r<-mat.I
d1<-mat.I[,which(mat.I[5,]==1)]
mat.I.r[sample(which(d1[1:4]==1),1),which(mat.I[5,]==1)]<-0
```

But this only deletes one of the two values I would like to delete.  I have also tried variations on subsetting the matrix, but I have not been successful.

Thank you again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a little bit of ambiguity in the description from the OP, so two solutions are suggested:

### Assuming that only existing `1`s in relevant columns can be set to `0`

I'll just alter the original function (see below). The change is to the line defining `rows`. I now have (there was a bug in the original - the version below is revised to handle deal with the bug):

```
rows <- sapply(seq_along(cols), 
                   function(x, mat, cols) {
                       ones <- which(mat[,cols[x]] == 1L)
                       out <- if(length(ones) == 1L) {
                                  ones
                              } else {
                                  sample(ones, 1)
                       }
                       out
                   }, mat = mat, cols = cols)
```

Basically, what this does is, for each column we need to swap a `1` to a `0`, we work out which rows of the column contain `1`s and sample one of these.

**Edit**: We have to handle the case where there is only a single `1` in a column. If we just sample from a length 1 vector, R's `sample()` will treat it as if we wanted to sample from the set `seq_len(n)` not from the length 1 set `n`. We handle this now with an `if, else` statement.

We have to do this individually for each column so we get the correct rows. I suppose we could do some nice manipulation to avoid repeated calls to `which()` and `sample()`, but how escapes me at the moment, because we do have to handle the case where there is only one `1` in the column. Here's the finished function (updated to handle the length 1 sample bug in the original):

```
foo <- function(mat, vec) {
    nr <- nrow(mat)
    nc <- ncol(mat)

    cols <- which(vec == 1L)
    rows <- sapply(seq_along(cols), 
                   function(x, mat, cols) {
                       ones <- which(mat[,cols[x]] == 1L)
                       out <- if(length(ones) == 1L) {
                                  ones
                              } else {
                                  sample(ones, 1)
                              }
                       out
                   }, mat = mat, cols = cols)

    ind <- (nr*(cols-1)) + rows
    mat[ind] <- 0

    mat <- rbind(mat, vec)
    rownames(mat) <- NULL

    mat
}
```

and here it is in action:

```
> set.seed(2)
> foo(mat1, ivec)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    1    0
```

and it works when there is only one `1` in a column we want to do a swap in:

```
> foo(mat1, c(0,0,1,1))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    0    1    1
```

### Original Answer: Assuming **any** value in a relevant column can be set to zero

Here is a vectorised answer, where we treat the matrix as a vector when doing the replacement. Using the example data:

```
mat1 <- matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1), byrow = TRUE, nrow = 4)
ivec <- c(0,1,1,0)

## Set a seed to make reproducible
set.seed(2)

## number of rows and columns of our matrix
nr <- nrow(mat1)
nc <- ncol(mat1)

## which of ivec are 1L
cols <- which(ivec == 1L)

## sample length(cols) row indices, with replacement
## so same row can be drawn more than once
rows <- sample(seq_len(nr), length(cols), replace = TRUE)

## Compute the index of each rows cols combination
## if we treated mat1 as a vector
ind <- (nr*(cols-1)) + rows
## ind should be of length length(cols)

## copy for illustration
mat2 <- mat1

## replace the indices we want with 0, note sub-setting as a vector
mat2[ind] <- 0

## bind on ivec
mat2 <- rbind(mat2, ivec)
```

This gives us:

```
> mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
        1    0    0    0
        0    1    0    0
        1    0    0    0
        0    0    1    1
ivec    0    1    1    0
```

If I were doing this more than once or twice, I'd wrap this in a function:

```
foo <- function(mat, vec) {
    nr <- nrow(mat)
    nc <- ncol(mat)

    cols <- which(vec == 1L)
    rows <- sample(seq_len(nr), length(cols), replace = TRUE)

    ind <- (nr*(cols-1)) + rows
    mat[ind] <- 0

    mat <- rbind(mat, vec)
    rownames(mat) <- NULL

    mat
}
```

Which gives:

```
> foo(mat1, ivec)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0    0
[3,]    1    0    1    0
[4,]    0    0    0    1
[5,]    0    1    1    0
```

If you wanted to do this for multiple `ivec`s, growing `mat1` each time, then you probably don't want to do that in a loop as growing objects is slow (it involves copies etc). But you could just modify the definition of `ind` to include the extra `n` rows you bind on for the `n` `ivec`s.

Comment: Very nice and afaik the fastest solution.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but with your last example the output still has 2 1's in the top 4 rows of the 2nd column.

Comment: @nzcoops the OP is unclear whether only a 1 at random has to be changed to 0 or is any random element in a relevant column needs to be set to zero. I'll provide an alternate version that only swaps 1s to 0s

Comment: @nzcoops Updated with a version that only swaps 1s to 0s.

Comment: @Gavin, true, I was going off the example which showed a 1 disappearing from both columns. Nice answer :) I couldn't think of a way out of the dreaded for loop :P Then again, if you're only doing it once on a small matrix and you can knock up a for loop quickly, guess there's no harm in that.

Comment: @Gavin Simpson - You could use `sample.int` instead to avoid problems: `out <- ones[sample.int(length(ones), 1)]`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this. Having 'nrow' in there will allow you to run it multiple times with other 'I.vec's. I tried to do this in a single line with 'apply' but couldn't get a matrix to come out again.

```
mat1<-matrix(c(1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1),byrow=T, nrow=4)
I.vec<-c(0,1,1,0)
mat.I.r<-rbind(mat1,I.vec)

for(i in 1:ncol(mat.I.r))
  {
  ifelse(mat.I.r[nrow(mat.I.r),i]==1, mat.I.r[sample(which(mat.I.r[1:(nrow(mat.I.r)-1),i]==1),1), i] <- 0, "")
  }
mat.I.r
```