# Subtracting from random values in a weighted matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sample, weighted

and thanks in advance for your help!

This question is related to one I posted [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855059/randomly-selecting-values-from-an-existing-matrix-after-adding-a-vector-in-r), but I think it deserves its own post because it is a separate challenge.

Last time I asked about randomly selecting values from a matrix after adding a vector.  In that example, the matrix and the vector were both binary.  Now I would like to change the values in a weighted matrix after adding a weighted vector.  Here is some example code to play with.

```
require(gamlss.dist)
mat1<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,10,0,0,0,5, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,3,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,3,0, 
  0,0,2,0,0,0, 2,1,0,1,0,1, 0,0,0,0,37,0, 0,0,0,2,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0,0,0, 
  0,1,1,0,0,0), byrow=T, ncol=6, nrow=12)

vec1<-c(0,0,0,1,1,1)
ones <- which(vec1 == 1L)
temp=rZIP(sum(vec1))      #rZIP is a function from gamlss.dist that randomly selects values from a zero-inflated distribution
vec1[ones]<-temp
```

The values in the vector are sampled from a zero-inflated distribution (thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034648/randomly-selecting-values-from-a-zero-inflated-distribution-in-r)).  When I bind the vector to the matrix, I want to randomly select a non zero value from the same column, and subtract the vector value from it.  I can see a further complication arising if the vector value is greater than the randomly selected value in the same column.  In such an instance, it would simply set that value to zero.

Here is some modified code from the earlier question that does not work for this problem but maybe will be helpful.

```
foo <- function(mat, vec) {
    nr <- nrow(mat)
    nc <- ncol(mat)
    cols <- which(vec != 0)        #select matrix columns where the vector is not zero
    rows <- sapply(seq_along(cols),
      function(x, mat, cols) {
        ones <- which(mat[,cols[x]] != 0)
        out <- if(length(ones) != 0) {
             ones
             } else {
                sample(ones, 1)
                }
             out
             }, mat = mat, cols = cols)
    ind <- (nr*(cols-1)) + rows           #this line doesn't work b/c it is not binary
    mat[ind] <- 0                         #here is where I would like to subtract the vector value
    mat <- rbind(mat, vec)
    rownames(mat) <- NULL
    mat
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks again for all of the fantastic help!

**EDIT:**

Thanks to help from bnaul down below, I am a lot closer to the answer, but we have run into the same problem we hit last time.  The sample function doesn't work properly on columns where there is only one nonzero value.  I have fixed this using Gavin Simpson's if else statement (which was the solution in the previous case). I've adjusted the matrix to have columns with only one nonzero value.

```
 mat1<-matrix(c(0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,5, 0,0,0,0,1,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,3,0, 
   0,0,2,0,0,0, 2,1,0,1,0,1, 0,0,0,0,37,0, 0,0,0,2,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,1, 1,0,0,0,0,0, 
   0,0,0,0,0,0), byrow=T, ncol=6, nrow=12)

vec1<-c(0,1,0,0,1,1)
ones <- which(vec1 == 1L)
temp=rZIP(sum(vec1))
vec1[ones]<-temp 

mat2 = rbind(mat1, vec1)     
apply(mat2, 2, function(col) {       #Returns matrix of integers indicating their column 
                                     #number in matrix-like object
    nonzero = which(head(col,-1) != 0);      #negative integer means all but last # of elements in x
    sample_ind = if(length(nonzero) == 1){
      nonzero
      } else{
        sample(nonzero, 1)
        }
        ;                             #sample nonzero elements one time
    col[sample_ind] = max(0, col[sample_ind] - tail(col,1));    #take max of either 0 or selected value minus Inv
    return(col)
    }
  )
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Although you provide sample data and even your attempts at code and links to old questions, I'm surprised nobody has taken this one up. Perhaps it is because it is not entirely clear what you want to do ("When I bind the vector to the matrix": what do you mean here?). Maybe you could clarify your intentions and/or show an example of your wanted results?

Comment: It might be because there are a couple of problems with the sample code; you don't define m, and you don't specify what package rZIP is from (gamlss). I am taking a stab at it now, though.

Comment: Sorry!  I will edit to make it more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mat2 = rbind(mat1, vec1)    
apply(mat2, 2, function(col) {
    nonzero = which(head(col,-1) != 0);
    sample_ind = sample(nonzero, 1);
    col[sample_ind] = max(0, col[sample_ind] - tail(col,1));
    return(col)
    }
)
```

I made a couple of simplifications; hopefully they don't conflict with what you had in mind. First, I ignore the requirement that you only operate on the nonzero elements of the vector, since subtracting 0 from anything will not change it. Second, I bind the matrix and vector and then perform the operation column-wise on the result, since this is a bit easier than tracking the indices in two separate data structures and then combining them afterward.

Comment: Fabulous, thank you...you really did a great job of cleaning up my messy code.

Comment: Sorry, I ran into a problem we ran into last time.  If there is only one value in the column to sample from, the sample function has a problem.  "...(in) the case where there is only a single 1 in a column...If we just sample from a length 1 vector, R's sample() will treat it as if we wanted to sample from the set seq_len(n) not from the length 1 set n."  Gavin Simpson handled it with an "if else" statement.  I will see if I can figure it out.